# Is there is a method or prop to debounce the main search of the table?

Tags: material-table

Hello everyone i want to make server side search using debounce method the and when i create a `ref` to the table and i logged it i found this method `onSearchChangeDebounce` but i didn't know how to use it, any ideas i'll be appreciated.
here is my code

```
<MaterialTable
    tableRef={ref => this.tableRef = ref}
    title={title}
    data={data}
    isLoading={store.loading}
    options={this.options}
    actions={this.actions}
    localization={this.localization}
    columns={this.columns}
    components={this.components}
    icons={this.icons}
    detailPanel={this.rowDetailsPanel}
    onChangeRowsPerPage={pageSize => this.handleChangePageSize(pageSize)}
    onSearchChange={data => this.handleServerSideSearch(data)}
/>

handleServerSideSearch(dataToSearch) {
    console.log(dataToSearch);
    // call api here after debounce
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the debounce inteval with the `debounceInterval` prop in options like this:

```
<MaterialTable
    tableRef={ref => this.tableRef = ref}
    title={title}
    data={data}
    isLoading={store.loading}
    options={{...this.options, debounceInterval: 1000}}
    actions={this.actions}
    localization={this.localization}
    columns={this.columns}
    components={this.components}
    icons={this.icons}
    detailPanel={this.rowDetailsPanel}
    onChangeRowsPerPage={pageSize => this.handleChangePageSize(pageSize)}
    onSearchChange={data => this.handleServerSideSearch(data)}
/>

handleServerSideSearch(dataToSearch) {
    console.log(dataToSearch);
    // call api here after debounce
}
```

This will call `handleServerSideSearch` 1 second after the last user search interaction.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked fine, but is there is any way to customize this behavior ? i want debounce only work for search Field which we enable it in options by `search: true `

Comment: Can you elaborate on your exact usecase?

Comment: please check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810657/how-to-use-server-side-pagination-with-client-filtration

Comment: Hi Domino. I wonder if I could trouble you to refrain from adding "hope this helps" or other similar sentiments in your answers. Undoubtedly everyone hopes their work helps, but it is redundant, and we surely do not want to add it to all 25M answers on the site. There is something of an expectation here that, since the site is not a discussion forum, that we use technical writing standards if we can. Thanks!