# How to use server side pagination with client filtration?

Tags: material-table

what i need is when i use remote data i want to be allowed to filter client side not server side here is my table [image: my table]

and my code for `remote data`

```
 <MaterialTable
   title={Strings.userManagementList}
   data={query => {
     this.get(query);
     return new Promise(resolve => event.on('data-fetched', resolve));
    }}
    isLoading={store.loading}
    options={this.options}
    actions={this.actions}
    localization={this.localization}
    columns={this.columns}
    components={this.components}
  />
```

this works fine but also the search bar in the top left corner `when i type in it, it calls the end point agin with search parameter` ---> this is normal but my problem is
`when i change filter or search from search bar ---> related to any column it also calls the endpoint`

so what i want is:
**1/ remote data**
**2/ only the top left search field used in trigger remote data again**
**3/ if i filter from columns filtration bar it searches inside the current table results no need to remote data unless i paginate or searched from the top left search field**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by saving the data returned by your query locally in your component.

Now if the only the filters of the query but not the page or the search parameter change, instead of calling `this.get(query);`, you access the locally saved data, filter that by the filter texts from the query object and return the filtered data in a promise instead of fetching new data.